# Guess the next number in the sequence 15 20 20 6 6 19 19 5 14 20 14 23 8 15?

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

What would you put next in the below sequence?

15 20 20 6 6 19 19 5 14 20 14 23 8 15 ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> 9

because

> converting to letters (A is 1, Z is 26) they're the first letters of "one" through "ten", followed by the second letters of "one" through "four". Then we need the second letter of "five", which is i: the **9**th letter of the alphabet.

Comment: Just to check, what if there were no repeating numbers, i.e., 15 20 6 19 5 14 20 14 23 8 15 ?, would it have been hard to solve?

Comment: @Hitesh: Probably not. The `OTTFFSSENT` sequence is burned into the brain of many puzzlers.

Answer (score 11):

**Answer is**

> **9**

bcz

> **15 20 20 6 6 19 19 5 14 20 14 23 8 15** makes **O T T F F S S E N T** 
>  The Letters are the initials of the series of 1 to 10 having equivalent position in alphabet.
>  Rest four are the second letters of exact series
>  **14 23 8 15** makes **N W H O**
>  Which are second letters in same series (Second letters of One,two,Three,Four)
>  so next digit is 5 and the letter will be **I**

so next number is

> **9**

Comment: May be the answer posted in mean time when I was writing mine :)

Comment: @Deusovi: With a four minute difference in posting times it seems likely that this was started before your answer was posted.

Comment: The explanation should probably be hidden along with the answer

Comment: Roger that @yitzih thanks for informing. :)

Comment: hey @Chris may be you wana say that i copied the answer. But I didn't. I wrote it bcz it came in my mind. Anyways, That also proves me clever who explained the thing other way. His and mine explanations have huge difference. Do you think that can be made up and posted just in 4 minutes?

Comment: @MaulikModi: Not sure why you are addressing that comment at me - you seem to be agreeing with what I said - that is that the four minutes difference in posting time was probably shorter than it took to write your answer. The conclusion being that you had started answering before Deusovi had finished writing theirs.

Comment: That's what i meant to say. I didn't cheat. :)